# Python Mechanize select_form() - ParseError: OPTION outside of SELECT

Tags: python, mechanize

I am using Python 2.7 and Mechanize 2.5. I am trying to use the select_form() method, but I am getting the following error:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 499, in select_form
    global_form = self._factory.global_form
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_html.py", line 544, in __getattr__
    self.forms()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_html.py", line 557, in forms
    self._forms_factory.forms())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_html.py", line 237, in forms
    _urlunparse=_rfc3986.urlunsplit,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_form.py", line 845, in ParseResponseEx
    _urlunparse=_urlunparse,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_form.py", line 982, in _ParseFileEx
    fp.feed(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_form.py", line 759, in feed
    _sgmllib_copy.SGMLParser.feed(self, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_sgmllib_copy.py", line 110, in feed
    self.goahead(0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_sgmllib_copy.py", line 144, in goahead
    k = self.parse_starttag(i)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_sgmllib_copy.py", line 302, in parse_starttag
    self.finish_starttag(tag, attrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_sgmllib_copy.py", line 347, in finish_starttag
    self.handle_starttag(tag, method, attrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_sgmllib_copy.py", line 387, in handle_starttag
    method(attrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_form.py", line 736, in do_option
    _AbstractFormParser._start_option(self, attrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_form.py", line 481, in _start_option
    raise ParseError("OPTION outside of SELECT")
ParseError: OPTION outside of SELECT
```

This is my code:

```
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
br.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
br.open("website_url_which_i_will_not_share")
br.select_form(nr=0)
```

The following is the form section of the html on the webpage that I opened

```
<html lang="en-us" xml:lang="en-us" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head> I omitted this section </head>
    <body class="login">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header" style="background-color: #13397A;">
            <div id="content" class="colM">
                <div id="content-main">
                    <form id="login-form" method="post" action="/admin/">
                        <div style="display:none">
                            <input type="hidden" value="8a689f2e3d215a3465f1bb66e037d1a5" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label class="required" for="id_username">Username:</label>
                            <input id="id_username" type="text" maxlength="30" name="username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label class="required" for="id_password">Password:</label>
                            <input id="id_password" type="password" name="password">
                            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="this_is_the_login_form">
                            <input type="hidden" value="/admin/" name="next">
                        </div>
                        <div class="submit-row">
                            <label>&nbsp;</label>
                            <input type="submit" value="Log in">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                </div>
                <br class="clear">
            </div>
            <div id="footer"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    </body>
</html>
```

I have researched this on stackoverflow and on google, but I cannot find a similar question or even a description of this error.

If anyone could tell me what this error means and help me find whats wrong here, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Edit: I have been doing a lot of form submitting and every site works fine except for this one. It is a database API, which I am trying to scrap data from.

Comment: In order to help, people need to be able to reproduce your problem, without full page source it is not really possible.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I edited my question to include all of the html (excluding the head tag)

Comment: The source you got with a web browser and the source mechanize request got may be different, for debugging purposes try to `print br.forms` before calling select_form. Perhaps the default parser can’t cope with invalid HTML (`<input...>` should be `<input.../>`?).

Comment: Good point about the html being invalid. I searched solutions for that and found this: br = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())

It seems to work now. Thank you.

Comment: @camelCase thanks for your solution. you should put your comment as an answer, because it works. this way it helps people better and :) you get the badge for Self-Learner if you accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (and unfortunately haven't solved it yet), and I found this interesting piece of code, it might help

From http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.wwwsearch.general/1991 (see [archive.org version](https://web.archive.org/web/20160417184901/http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.wwwsearch.general/1991))

```
import   mechanize
from   BeautifulSoup   import  BeautifulSoup  

class SanitizeHandler(mechanize.BaseHandler):
    def http_response(self, request, response):
        if not hasattr(response, "seek"):
            response = mechanize.response_seek_wrapper(response)
        #if    HTML   used   get   it though  a    robust  Parser    like  BeautifulSoup

        if response.info().dict.has_key('content-type') and ('html' in response.info().dict['content-type']):
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.get_data())
            response.set_data(soup.prettify())
        return response

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.add_handler(SanitizeHandler())

# Now    you get    good   HTML
```

This should override the http_response method and "clean" your html.

Comment: The posted source is dead. Can you give any more info on why this is a solution?